# JSON.parse() not working for nested arrays

Tags: arrays, json, parsing

I'm trying to parse a object which have nested elements. The stringified json looks like this:

```
{"baseData.tags":{"in":"[60ddb3f0d12020ec8558a926,60ddb3f0d12020ec8558a926]"},"skip":"0"}
```

The parsed json (JSON.parse(stringifiedObject)) looks like this:

```
{
  'baseData.tags': { '$in': '[60ddb3f0d12020ec8558a926,60ddb3f0d12020ec8558a926]' },
  skip: '0'
}
```

The nested array is still a string.

I also tried to loop through the object keys and parse the nested objects.

```
const jsonQueryParser = (json: any) => {
  const jsonResult = { ...json };
  const objectKeys = Object.keys(jsonResult);

  for (let i = 0; i < objectKeys.length; i++) {
    let parsedJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonResult[objectKeys[i]]));
    
    if (typeof parsedJson === 'object') {
      parsedJson = jsonQueryParser(parsedJson);
    }

    jsonResult[objectKeys[i]] = parsedJson;
  }

  return jsonResult;
};
```

But still get the same result with the array as string.

Does anyone have an idea how to parse a nested object with array values?

Comment: The json parser is working correctly, that "nested array" really is a string per the JSON spec. Can you change the string you're parsing? It should be `{"baseData.tags":{"in":["60ddb3f0d12020ec8558a926","60ddb3f0d12020ec8558a926"]},"skip":"0"}` instead.

Comment: Hi @AnthonyManning-Franklin thank you for your answer. Your right, thats working. My problem is that the string I need to parse comes from the node express query. I call the REST API like this: http://localhost:3000/events/?baseData.tags[in]=["60ddb3f0d12020ec8558a926","60ddb3f0d12020ec8558a926"]&skip=0
and the req.query I get looks like that: {
  'baseData.tags': { in: '["60ddb3f0d12020ec8558a926","60ddb3f0d12020ec8558a926"]' },
  skip: '0'
}

Comment: I just found a solution. I have to pass the array in the request like that:
http://localhost:3000/events?baseData.tags[in]=60ddb3f0d12020ec8558a922&baseData.tags[in]=60ddb3f0d12020ec8558a926&baseData.tags[in]=60ddb3f0d12020ec8558a927